# Using DotNetNuke MVC module for big projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

We created many modules by dotnetnuke (web-form).We want to create a big project (**BPMS**) by DotNetNuke MVC module (If it is possible). I began to create a small project for test DotNetNuke MVC module. At first I need to use **Telerik** controls in partial view. I put many hours to do it but every time I was faced with limitations in DotNetNuke MVC module. For example in [this](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/forumid/203/threadid/533258/scope/posts) post discussed a problem that it is similar to my problem.

Finally I think DotNetNuke MVC module is not very convenient tool for this project. Do you agree with me?

Thank a lot.

Comment: this site is for code based questions.  This question and its answers will be opinion based.  Please consider having this discussion in another forum.

Comment: @JKing Thanks for this comment but stackoverflow isn't just for code based questions. See this Tags [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) , ...

Comment: I appreciate the dialog.  I think the challenge is the answer to your question is opinion based.  You don't actually post a problem to be fixed or define a problem, but you ask for agreement with a statement you just made.  You define your project as a big project.  What does that mean, what specific MVC limitations are limiting your project and what is your project trying to achieve that is not working?  Without these details, this is a question that cannot be answered by others and also, won't be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Looking only at the technical aspects of what you are trying to accomplish, and trying to shy away from "is this right for your project" which is more opinon based.

The Telerik controls that are included in the DNN system are all WebForms controls and functions.  This means that they are usable within your older WebForms modules, but if you switch to using the MVC Module method you cannot use those controls any longer.  There are other limitations in making a switch from WebForms to MVC, such as the usage of the RichTextEditor which is designed for WebForms.

Making a transition from WebForms to MVC, in DNN and other projects, is not a simple one-to-one process and you will have technical limitations.